DirectJDKLog errors with temporary files (DiskFileItem.delete)
I have a Spring Boot application in which the underlying tomcat regularly throws an error like this:
2024-06-11 11:12:40,529 ERROR [http-nio-9312-exec-5] <org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog>: Error processing request
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\Windows\Temp\tomcat.9312.3138704811626004803\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_f2043be0_7945_4211_b735_367546c4255b_00000000.tmp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:429)
    [...]
2024-06-11 11:12:40,536 ERROR [http-nio-9312-exec-5] <org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog>: Error reading request, ignored
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\Windows\Temp\tomcat.9312.3138704811626004803\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_f2043be0_7945_4211_b735_367546c4255b_00000000.tmp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:429)
    [...]
2024-06-11 11:12:40,537 ERROR [http-nio-9312-exec-5] <org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog>: Error running socket processor
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\Windows\Temp\tomcat.9312.3138704811626004803\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_f2043be0_7945_4211_b735_367546c4255b_00000000.tmp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:429)
    [...]

I have checked, and while the Folder C:\Windows\Temp\tomcat.9312.3138704811626004803\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\ exists, the file upload_f2043be0_7945_4211_b735_367546c4255b_00000000.tmp does not.
I have already tried setting spring.servlet.multipart.location to a less protected location, but the same error still occurred in that case. What's more, in that case it resulted in files and folders that I could not even delete with administrator rights.
This happens when the following endpoint is called:
@PostMapping(
    value = "/validate",
    consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ValidationResponse validateUploadedFile(
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
) {
    try {
        validator.validateMultipartFile(file);
        return ValidationResponse.buildValidResponse();
    } catch (ValidationFailedException e) {
        return ValidationResponse.buildValidationFailedResponse(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ValidationResponse.buildInvalidResponse(
            "Unexpected exception occurred while trying to validate file: <"
                + e.getClass()
                + "> "
                + e.getMessage()
        );
    }
}

The funny thing is that the request always passes, so whatever this exception is, it appears afterwards, and I have no idea what to do about it.
Does anyone have any suggestions? I am using Spring Boot version 3.3.0
